# Puppeteer is not able to install: "ERROR: Failed to set up Chromium r782078! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download"

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to install Puppeteer in Windows 10 using the below command and am getting an error.

The command used to install Puppeteer:

```
npm install --save PUPPETEER
```

Error:

```
ERROR: Failed to set up Chromium r782078! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.
Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

I have also tried the below option, but I am still getting the same error.

```
npm install -g puppeteer --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

Answer (score 73):

**Note**: This is for [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver). However, it should be a similar process for Windows though.

Set the environment variable (as the error suggests):

**Mac**

`export PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD='true'`

**Windows**

`SET PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD='true'`

and then...

`npm i puppeteer`

Comment: See https://www.architectryan.com/2018/08/31/how-to-change-environment-variables-on-windows-10/ for setting Windows environment variables.

Comment: In Windows, use set instead of export

Comment: worked in windows, added in environment variables.

Comment: got the similar error on macbook as well, with node 14, but problem is not fixed

Comment: finally this helps: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6492#issuecomment-859109456

Comment: This environment variable doesn't do anything, it seems; @BMW's link points to a workaround (`--unsafe-perm`)

Comment: BMW's link helps. @BMW if you decide to convert your comment into an answer I would give you an upvote : }

Answer (score 28):

This works for me:

```
npm install --ignore-scripts puppeteer
```

Answer (score 15):

Set an npm mirror:

```
npm config set puppeteer_download_host=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors
npm i puppeteer
```

It will work.

Comment: Current versions of puppeteer uses this env var: PUPPETEER_DOWNLOAD_BASE_URL

Answer (score 8):

**Note:** It works for [MacBook M1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro#Sixth_generation_(M1)) and Node.js 16

```
export PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true
export PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=`which chromium`
```

Comment: Not working for me on Macbook Pro intel so any alternative ?

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
npm install puppeteer --unsafe-perm
```

It worked for me.

Comment: tried npm install puppeteer --unsafe-perm got this error npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'pickAlgorithm')

Answer (score 4):

#### On Windows ([PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell))

Do this before installation:

```
$env:PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD="true"
```

Comment: For some reason PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD didn't work, but PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD did. I added the setting by going to Advanced System Settings and manullay enter the evironment variable in the User variables. Your way is better though (using terminal commands on Windows is always a challenge).

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was connected to a [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) which caused me issue in installing Puppeteer.

Comment: maybe same issue for me but I can't disable VPN

Comment: yes, the same thing for me. I disabled proxy in terminal by setting "unsetproxy", then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
npm install --ignore-scripts puppeteer
```

Comment: It would be great to add a few words explaining what this does compared to the existing answers

Comment: This is identical to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73139328/4032703).

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete Puppeteer from *[package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/)* and redo `npm install`, in order to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run *stencil.js* and start its developer server, in running the `npm install` command I had the above error, and by using a recommendation I handled the problem.

Comment: What recommendation? From other answers to this question?

Answer (score 0):

```bash
npm install -g cnpm --registry=https://registry.npm.taobao.org

cnpm install puppeteer --save
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.