# Program can't set up Chromium to install Pupeteer using Node JS

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install Pupeteer onto Node JS but when I ran the install command I got this error message. I am very much a newb when it comes to this sort of stuff and was planning to just start coding and have some fun, but I obviously can't do that if I cannot install the program in the first place. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install -g puppeteer
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\phurs\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\puppeteer
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node install.js
npm ERR! ERROR: Failed to set up Chromium r950341! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.
npm ERR! Error: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR!     at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:220:20) {
npm ERR!   errno: -4077,
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNRESET',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'read'
npm ERR! }
```

Comment: Is Chromium installed on your machine? Also, have you tried any of the solutions from this page https://stackoverflow.com/q/63187371/5358219.

Comment: I looked the the pages but I didn't find that, I will try that out now. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Okay, I've tried some stuff out and it seems to have worked; instead of getting the error message as mentioned above I get this: `C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install puppeteer

up to date, audited 58 packages in 852ms

8 packages are looking for funding
  run npm fund for details

found 0 vulnerabilities`