# ERROR: Failed to set up Chrome r116.0.5845.96

Tags: node.js, docker, puppeteer, chromium

I am using node.js for a project where I need a headless browser

I am using  "puppeteer": "21.2.1", in my pakcage.json

I am using pnpm

for pnpm install every thing is working fine

but from docker compose

```
RUN npm pkg delete scripts.prepare && npm i --location=global pnpm@${PNPM_VERSION}
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=pnpm,target=/root/.local/share/pnpm/store/v3 pnpm fetch

RUN --mount=type=cache,id=pnpm-store,target=/root/.local/share/pnpm/store/v3 \
    pnpm install --prefer-offline --frozen-lockfile
```

- this is just part of the file-

I keep getting this error :

> ERROR: Failed to set up Chrome r116.0.5845.96! Set
> "PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.

I have seen that there is something similar in this thread

[Puppeteer is not able to install: "ERROR: Failed to set up Chromium r782078! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63187371/puppeteer-is-not-able-to-install-error-failed-to-set-up-chromium-r782078-set)

but none of the solutions worked for me

1- SET PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD='true' (even though I need it and I do not want to skip )

2- npm install --ignore-scripts puppeteer

3-npm config set puppeteer_download_host=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors

4-set PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=`which chromium`

5-from powershell $env:PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD="true"

6- with or without VPN

7- deleted the node modules

8- used no cache

the versions I am using :

node v20.6.1

pnpm (not npm and I took this in my consideration when I was running the commands) 7.33.6